# Terminal window interprets quick initial q as macro record

Tags: key-bindings, macro, terminal-buffer

I have a function that opens a terminal window running some program. The program is quit by pressing `q`. But when I press `q` in the terminal window shortly after (within 1-2 seconds) of it being opened, it is instead interpreted by vim as starting macro recording. This only happens if it is the first key I press in the terminal window. Why does this happen and is there a way to stop it?

Comment: Are you running Neovim?

Comment: @Matt It's Vim 8.2

Comment: Since I don't see this behavior with my [simpl](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-simpl) plugin, I'll point you towards [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: A possible answer is that you start your terminal in normal mode. I am not sure it applies to vim as saw this on nvim.